# How to get string from ReadOnlyMemory<char> without allocation?

Tags: c#, memory-management, allocation

Can we get string reference from `ReadonlyMemory<char>` without re-allocating on heap.

```cs
ReadonlyMemory<char> someChars;//I got ReadOnlyMemory<char> from somewhere
string str = someChars.SomeMethodToGetStringWithoutAllocation();//I am looking for this
```

Comment: This ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.trygetstring?view=net-5.0

Comment: Yes, please put in answer. I will mark it as answer.

Comment: Don't want to, since I have basically no knowledge about this topic and just simply googled "c# ReadonlyMemory<char> get string" and this was the first hit, I don't deserve points for this :)

Comment: @RandRandom If you encounter this question in the SO sarch results, it shows having no answers, but actually, it has.

Comment: @Bolpat - very true indeed, if you want to you can fix it by giving an answer yourself, still don't feel like doing it myself

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the same memory using the `TryGetString` method of the `MemoryMarshal` class (as noted in the comments).

However, looking at [the implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/MemoryMarshal.cs,1393d02833083ced,references) it seems like this will only work if the memory was originally obtained from a string instance otherwise this method will fail (the internal method `GetObjectStartLength` will return false).

```
ReadOnlyMemory<char> s = "foo".AsMemory();
var ok = System.Runtime.InteropServices.MemoryMarshal.TryGetString(s, out string s2, out int start2, out int length2);
Console.WriteLine(ok);      // True
Console.WriteLine(s2);      // foo
Console.WriteLine(start2);  // 0
Console.WriteLine(length2); // 3

ReadOnlyMemory<char> s3 = "foo".ToCharArray();
var ok2 = System.Runtime.InteropServices.MemoryMarshal.TryGetString(s3, out string s4, out int start4, out int length4);
Console.WriteLine(ok2);     // False
Console.WriteLine(s4);      // null
Console.WriteLine(start4);  // 0
Console.WriteLine(length4); // 0
```

Note: the string reference is the original string reference. `TryGetString` it is like an unwrap of a `ReadOnlyMemory<char>`.